# DebugView doesn't work on Windows 10

Tags: kernel, trace, windows-10, debugview

I can't capture trace from kernel, using WinDbg on Windows 10 x86. Seems troubles with old signature. Are there any alternatives which could receive DbgPrint from kernel driver?

Comment: Have you tried the SysInternals' [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) tool? The latest version of WinDbg is in the Windows 10 SDK, and the RTM version of that comes out next week.